# Error showing in the installation of git in ubuntu 18.04.2LTS

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am trying to install git by the command.

```
sudo apt install git
```

Showing Error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (> 1:2.17.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (< 1:2.17.1-.) but it is not going to be installed
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Also, Tried to run the command `apt --fix-broken install` but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to see there :
I use ubuntu 20.04, but it run for me.

```
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-git-on-ubuntu-18-04/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try updating all of your existing packages first with `sudo apt-get upgrade`. After that you might want to run the `sudo apt-get autoclean`. Finally have a go at installing git again `sudo apt-get install git`.

Comment: I did but not work, showing =>
>
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).>

Comment: Looks like it points to the fact that mongodb is not installed, although you'd expect apt to automatically install all of the dependencies. Try installing it manually first maybe? `sudo apt-get install mongodb-org`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install git
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo apt update
```

From: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2454450